# Adding points to multiple boxplot in echarts4r

Tags: jquery, boxplot, echarts, echarts4r

I just have a small question. I am trying to plot multiple boxplots on a single chart and I want all the data points used for the box plot to be displayed on the chart. However, I am unable to do so. I tried using the e_scatter function after the e_boxplot function but it is not working as intended. Would be great if someone could help me out here. Sincerely thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`?